# Paypal API, Curl not returning any output

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I'm trying to figure out the Paypal API, and I have the following code, which should make a call, get an access token, and then make the API call. The first part works (up until the `$accesstoken` line), and returns the access token properly, but the second part doesn't return anything. The code this is supposed to mimic can be found here: [Make Your First Call](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/)

```
$url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";
$headers = array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language' => 'en_US',
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientID . ':' . $clientSecret);
$curl = curl_exec($ch);

$x = json_decode($curl, TRUE);
print_r($x);
$accesstoken = $x['access_token'];


$headers2 = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer' . $accesstoken
);

$data = array(
    "intent" => "sale",
    "redirect_urls" => array(
        "return_url" => "http://example.com/your_redirect_url/",
        "cancel_url" => "http://example.com/your_cancel_url/"
    ),
    "payer" => array(
        "payment_method" => "paypal"
    ),
    "transactions" => array(
        "transactions" => array(
            "total" => ".99",
            "currency" => "USD"
        )
    )
);

$saleurl = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment";

$sale = curl_init();
curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_URL, $saleurl);
curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);
$finalsale = curl_exec($sale);

$verb = json_decode($finalsale, TRUE);
print_r($verb);
```

Curl doesn't make complete sense to me, any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I changed the format of the headers to:

```
$headers2 = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accesstoken
);
```

as per one of the answers. Now it is displaying:

```
[name] => MALFORMED_REQUEST
[message] => Incoming JSON request does not map to API request
[information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST
[debug_id] => f53a882702a04
```

Comment: In your production code always verify peer and verify host for security: http://docforge.com/wiki/PHP/Curl

Comment: never assume that an external call succeeded. You're not checking either return value from curl_exec() for a boolean false, which would indicate failure. You simply take the returned value and try to json_decode it. at minimum you should have something more like `if (($result = $curl_exec($handle) === FALSE) { die(curl_error($handle)); }`

Comment: @Matt, I'm testing right now, but of course SSL is a must once I'm online.

Comment: @Marc I tried: if (($result = curl_exec($sale)) === FALSE){ echo "Error."; die(curl_error($sale)); } but it didn't trigger. I'm looking into curl debugging commands now.

Comment: (Shameless plug) If you run it through Runscope you can see what the API is returning more easily. https://www.runscope.com/provider-guide/troubleshooting-api-requests

Comment: Use curl_error() to get any errors and output them. You can use that function to see if your call failed
if(($e = curl_error($ch)))

Comment: All the curl_error outputs seem to be empty strings. "No errors" I guess -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting your headers correctly ...

```
$headers = array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Language: en_US'
);
```

and

```
$headers2 = array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accesstoken
);
```

Is the correct format.

Also note the (space) after Bearer inbetween your $accesstoken

Edit: Update for your JSON ( i think this is right but echo it out and check it against the reference, I might have one to many array()

```
$data = array(
    "intent" => "sale",
    "redirect_urls" => array(
        "return_url" => "http://example.com/your_redirect_url/",
        "cancel_url" => "http://example.com/your_cancel_url/"
    ),
    "payer" => array(
        "payment_method" => "paypal"
    ),
    "transactions" => array(array(
            "amount" => array(
                "total" => ".99",
                "currency" => "USD"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Now its giving an error about a Malformed request, "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"

Comment: Now it's giving me: "Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands separator ',', limited to 7 digits before the decimal point"

Comment: adding in a 0 (0.99 vs .99) fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space here

```
$headers2 = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accesstoken // Added a space after Bearer
);
```

See if it works now

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything, though you are right about the space, I meant to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Change
    curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));

to 
    curl_setopt($sale, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

The json encode function breaks it